# Unclikable "watch on youtube" link when embedding into iOS (and Android?) due to overlapping <video> element

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube-api

We are trying to embed YouTube videos into iOS WebFrame (whole frame is actually just a box for YouTube iFrame). Certain videos are not playable in the app unfortunately. For example, you can get "video contains content from MLB.. restricted from playback on certain sites" and then a link "Watch on YouTube".

The problem is that this "Watch on YouTube" link is unclickable, because later in the HTML there is a  element with data-youtube-id pointing to the requested video and, well, this unplayable video covers all the screen on top of a link making it unclickable.

On desktop browsers links are able to "shine through" the unplayable video (but you can't e.g. select "video contains.." text next to it). On mobile they don't.

Opening YouTube's frame in a stand-alone browser I am able to "fix" the problem by manually deleting that video element, then everything looks and works fine (so it's really an overlapping issue). In the app's WebView I cannot really mess with the iframe content and.. what do you do then?

Has anybody observe similar problem? What do you do about it? Can you somehow kill the unplayable video element inside iFrame? Or can you detect that there is a "video contains.." issue from outside of the iframe and display your own controls in the host page level then?

Or shall we just hope that YouTube developers note this post and take it as a bug report?

Comment: Hi, did you solve this ? I've the same problem in the iOS UIWebView. The same web page works in the Mac WebView on OSX.

Comment: I didn't solve the actual problem. That would require manipulating the iframe content or even producing better html yourself - that's very error-prone and well, as full of can of worms as any unifficial API use.

I did, however, figure how to decrease a need for a fix in the first place. Most of videos forbidden are forbidden, because file:/// is not one of the allowed sites for playback. Well, then you can make UIWebView think it's base URL is actually http://www.youtube.com ;)
That sure means that including more scripts could be pain, but that's fine for our case with nearly empty wrapper.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks! and how do you make UIWebView believe the base URL is youtube.com ?

Comment: When you call loadHTMLString, you can specify baseURL to be, for example, "http://www.youtube.com"

Comment: Could it be that those links are working now ? I've had the same problem for a very long time and now all of a sudden the link works, I click it and after a few seconds the youtube page with the video loads..